# How do i test a SOAP webservice using Jmeter 5.0

Tags: soap

Using Apache JMeter (5.0 r184095), and the template "Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan", how do I test http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?

Can someone show me exactly what to write in each field in order to get a working example?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it....

Used Postman to make a succesful call to the webservice, then looking in Fiddler for the headers. Copied all headers into  HTTP Header Manager in Jmeter.
Then got decoding error sent back from webservice. Changed Body Data in jmeter to not contain special characters